# How do I filter by calculation on associated tables?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to write an ActiveRecord query to filter all the variants where the variant’s price is **less than** its comparisons’ prices. Here’s my variant model:

```
class Variant < ApplicationRecord

  has_and_belongs_to_many :comparisons,
    class_name: "Variant",
    foreign_key: "competitor_variant_id",
    association_foreign_key: "account_variant_id",
    join_table: "comparisons"

  belongs_to :parent, polymorphic: true

end
```

Here’s what I’ve got so far:

```
joins(:comparisons).where('variants.price < comparisons_variants.min(:price)').distinct
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't completely understand what you have, but a Variant is being compared to other variants, correct?
It that is the case, I assume the comparisons table is something like:
`(variant_id, comparison_id)` where both are IDs of `Variant` values.

If so, something like this should work:
left join to the comparison table and then to the compared values that have a lower price, and if the count of such compared is 0, then the variant must have the lowest price.

```
scope :with_lowest_price, ->{
    joins("left join comparisons on comparisons.variant_id = variants.id left join variants as compared on comparisons.comparison_id = compared.id and variants.price >= compared.price")
      .group("variants.id")
      .having("count(compared.id)= 0")
  }
```